# How do I call a second project from the startup one in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a startup project and I want to do a `process.Start();` on a second project in the same solution. But using `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "SecondAssemblyName.exe");` as `FileName`  doesn't work. What does?

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Can you show us a little bit more of what you are doing with the `Path` in regards to starting the `Process`?

Comment: Is the second assembly being output to the same `bin` output location as the startup project?

Comment: @IAbstract yup. `The system cannot find the file specified`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, each project builds to its own directory, so you would have something like:

```
\MySolution
    \ProjectOne
        \bin
            ProjectOne.exe
    \ProjectTwo
        \bin
            ProjectTwo.exe
```

So your command to execute the other .exe does not work because they are built to separate folders.

You can fix this by doing one of a few things. You can add a post-build step to copy one .exe to the others \bin folder. Or you could change the build output paths of the projects to build to the same location.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Process.Start, but you need to supply the correct path to the other project.

This simplest solution would be to change the output folder in the build settings for each project.  If you build both projects to a shared output folder, you can just use Process.Start as you entered.

Answer (score 0):

you can start two project on debug doing the following:

click under solution -> Set StartUp Projects

in the windows opened click in Startup Project.

Select the option multiple startup projects and select the projects.

So you can run both as same time at debug and running into visual studio

Comment: Thanks. But I only want one to start at startup.